parse Request in Next.js 14
I want to get searchParams from Request which i get from Next.js auth
async authorize(credentials, req) {

}

if i do req.url i get only url string with callback without hash from URLSearchParams and rew.url.searchParams I get underfined. Parsing it to JSON does not work as well

